# Disappearance of GET parameters

Tags: redirect, browser, samsung-mobile, samsung-galaxy

Our GET parameters are disappearing specifically on Samsung mobile devices when using our 302 redirect URL. Do you know why this might be happening?

We want to ensure that after the redirect, users are taken to the expected URI just like on other devices.

Comment: HTTP redirections don't cause browsers to implicitly include query parameters - your server-side code needs to explicitly include them when it generates the `Location:` header... the fact you're asking this question now makes me want to ask "what browser *did* seemingly implicitly include existing query-string params?"